# EC2 openssh go back from 8.1 to 7.6

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssh

To have my server certified PCI I update the openssh version from 7.6 which should be the default one on aws ec2 to 8.1 running the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libpam0g-dev
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/openssh_8.1p1.orig.tar.gz
tar -xvf openssh_8.1p1.orig.tar.gz
cd openssh_8.1p1
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --with-md5-passwords --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd --with-pam
sudo make install
```

Working great, running `ssh -V` I have

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

But I do not really have the exact delay, a few days later the openssh version goes back to 7.6

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the OS (Ubuntu) has updated its SSH package overwriting your changes. The first thing to work out if you actually need the updated SSH or if you can use the operating systems version. If you really need the upgrade then work out how to prevent the os from replacing it.